# R Summary Stat by Logical vector grouping

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators, summary

I have the following R data frames.  I am trying to get summary stats by the logical vector grouping from the final "score" data frame.

```
    #original df
    type <- c("A", "B", "C","D","E")
    user <- c('user1','user2','user3','user4','user5')
    text <-c('this is a tweet','this is a fb post','tweeting is fun','other text','another fb post')
    tweet.mention <- c('TRUE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE')
    fb.mention <- c('FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE')
    df1 <- cbind.data.frame(type, user, text,tweet.mention,fb.mention)
    df1

   #Remove records that are all FALSE
   tweet<-as.logical(tweet.mention)
   fb<-as.logical(fb.mention)
   test<-cbind(tweet,fb)
   true<-rowSums(test)
   all<-cbind(test,true)

   #Create score df
   score<-subset(df1,true>=1)

   #score API return
   sentiment<-c(1,.5,2,-2)

   #scored text
   score<-cbind(score,sentiment)
```

The score df removed record 4 as it should and contains the scored numeric value.  Then I would like to get average sentiment score but grouped by tweet.mention(1.5) and fb.mention(-.75).  I have tried summary from base R but that is all in.  Thus I think a group by or subset is needed.  I then tried the describeBy from the psych package.  That isn't helping either.

Making matters more complicated is that I won't always know the number of logical vectors so can't subset them manually by specifying the column and having ==TRUE.  I can create a list or vector of the column headers to lapply through but I am unsure the coding or function to get the grouping done.

I have read the base r and psych vignettes as well as checked the R Cookbook for this answer but cannot find it.  I appreciate the help greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 methods using base R:

```
> with(score, tapply(sentiment, list(tweet.mention, fb.mention), mean))
      FALSE  TRUE
FALSE    NA -0.75
TRUE    1.5    NA
```

and:

```
> aggregate(sentiment~tweet.mention+fb.mention, data=score, mean)
  tweet.mention fb.mention sentiment
1          TRUE      FALSE      1.50
2         FALSE       TRUE     -0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution using the `data.table` package; there are multiple ways to do this.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(score)
score[, mean(sentiment), by = list(tweet.mention, fb.mention)]
```

It makes use of the `by` keyword in `data.table` for grouping. The output is:

```
   tweet.mention fb.mention    V1
1:          TRUE      FALSE  1.50
2:         FALSE       TRUE -0.75
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will use and also explore the data.table package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `dplyr`. You may want to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. In this way you can avoid making all variables factors here.

```
df1 %>%
    filter(tweet.mention != FALSE | fb.mention != FALSE) %>%
    mutate(sentiment = c(1, 0.5, 2, -2)) %>%
    group_by(tweet.mention, fb.mention) %>%
    summarize(outcome = mean(sentiment))

#  tweet.mention fb.mention outcome
#1         FALSE       TRUE   -0.75
#2          TRUE      FALSE    1.50
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <-structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), user = c("user1", 
"user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"), text = c("this is a tweet", 
"this is a fb post", "tweeting is fun", "other text", "another fb post"
), tweet.mention = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE"
), fb.mention = c("FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE")), .Names = c("type", 
"user", "text", "tweet.mention", "fb.mention"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```